# Implicit topic switching

Tags: composition

I'm wondering -- is something like

> ジョンが迷っていると気づいたら、何とかしないと、と。**ジョンなら絶対に出来る、と言った瞬間、突然ハンドルをつかんで引いた。** その痛烈な性格の変化は今でも鮮明に覚えている。

considered sloppy writing, or is it acceptable?

These are the intended topics/subjects:

> （私は）ジョンが迷っていると気づいたら、何とかしないと、と。**（私が）ジョンなら絶対に出来る、と言った瞬間、（ジョンは）突然ハンドルをつかんで引いた。**（私は）その痛烈な性格の変化は今でも鮮明に覚えている。

Namely, in the bolded sentence, the topic switches from 私 to ジョン, made especially confusing due to the subject of the embedded sentence under 瞬間 being 私, in addition to the surrounding sentences having 私 as their topic.

In English fiction, it's not uncommon to intentionally make the reader think about who is doing or saying what by leaving things more ambiguous than one normally would. I assume it's the same with Japanese fiction, but I'm wondering if this specific method doing of it is considered acceptable.

Comment: I can totally understand if this gets closed for being too subjective. That said, I often have composition questions like this, and I think they are probably of interest to many learners. I am curious how to properly formulate them for JLSE.

Comment: ハンドルをつかんで[弾]{はじ}いた？or [弾]{ひ}いた? 何のハンドル？　（「突然で」の「で」は、いりません）

Comment: @Unknown Thanks, fixed. No idea what handle, I just made up the examples. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is totally normal and acceptable, which is exactly why you as well as others understood the sentence itself and the passage.

If a "person" performs an unexpected action the moment you have made a statement, that person would ***not*** be yourself nearly 100% of the time, would it?  Thus, the author is successfully communicating with the readers.

In addition, the sentence that follows backs up the reader's understanding of the **bolded** sentence because one would ***not*** say 「その**痛烈な**性格の変化」 to describe a change in one's own character.

Generally speaking, placing a subject where it can be omitted for the reader comprehension could easily break the rhythm and flow of the writing, which any professional writer would like to avoid doing.